# How to style Android apps like the Play Store

Tags: android, android-xml, google-play

I want to define a xml layout which is like the Play Store. The following image shows what I want to define, I want to have the style Google Play uses in displaying the applications. Is there any library or reference I can use to achieve this goal.

---

[image]

Comment: Lastly I Found how could I achieve this style, I found this link which answered my question [GOOGLE NOW (ANDROID) CARD UI, THE EASY WAY](http://joeldeandev.com/google-now-card-ui-the-easy-way/)

Comment: No offence but that Tutorial still has performance problems, your better off using nine patch images!

Comment: Do you have a better solution than this, I am still a beginner in android development

Comment: Yes I do, use 9Patch images! Have a look at this http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-card-layout.html I precisely describe what you need to do. Its for a listView, you can just replace it with a GridView !

Answer (score 2):

You will use a GridView and apply a Card background to the grid. You could even look at staggered GridView if you want grids of unequal sizes.

Staggered Grid View : https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

Card Layout : http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-card-layout.html (My blog)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be filled with the GridView

Comment: but how can I have this style ?